# Probability of large Unions

Tags: probability

Given a large number of independent events, how does find the probability that exactly one occurs, in terms of the individual probabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, for example, we have four independent events $A, B, C, D$, with probabilities $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ respectively, then the probability exactly one occurs is
$$a(1-b)(1-c)(1-d)+(1-a)(b)(1-c)(1-d)+(1-a)(1-b)(c)(1-d)+(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)(d).$$
The first term in the above sum is the probability that $A$ occurs, and the others don't. The other terms can be explained similarly.

The same idea works generally. Suppose that $A_1,\dots,A_n$ are independent, and occur with probabilities $p_1,\dots,p_n$, and none of the $p_i$ is $1$.  The resulting formula is awkward to write out if we use the above notation.  But one can write the proability that exactly one occurs fairly neatly as
$$(1-p_1)(1-p_2)\cdots(1-p_n)\left[\frac{p_1}{1-p_1}+\frac{p_2}{1-p_2}+\cdots+\frac{p_n}{1-p_n}             \right].$$

If we have $n$ independent events, each of which has probability $p$, the probability that exactly one occurs is given by the simple expression $np(1-p)^{n-1}$.

Comment: I just relieved that I think I was wanting the probability of any one occurring. You answered what I wrote though so you get the check mark.

Comment: If you want the probability that **at least one** occurs, this is $1$ minus the probability they all fail. For the $4$ case, this is $1-(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)(1-d)$, much simpler than the **exactly** one of your question.

Comment: Cool Thanks. Sorry for the mix up.